# Query Environment hub records from salesforce API

Tags: google-chrome, salesforce, visualforce, apex, callouts

I'm currently creating a chrome extension that will query EnvironmentHubMember records from our Salesforce org, however  I'm currently getting this returned from the REST callout;

'"sObject type 'EnvironmentHubMember' is not supported."'

The endpoint I'm using is 'INSTANCENAME.COM/services/data/v20.0/query/?q=SELECT+Name+FROM+EnvironmentHubMember

I can't seem to find any specific settings to make this sObject available via an api call, has anybody been able to query these records from an external system before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try using a later API version.  The object itself was not available in version 20.  The most recent version is 41.